# How to assign numbers (10,11,12,13,14,15) to letters (A,B,C,D,E,F) in python 3?

Tags: python

I recently wrote a program that converts base 10 numbers to hexadecimal without using any built-in python functions. The way it works is it divides the user-inputted number by base 16 (each time updating the value of the number to be the quotient from the last division), until you get a quotient of zero. It keeps track of the remainders, and collects them in a list, and outputs the list as a number in hexadecimal base. However, if the code outputs any collection of numbers containing 10,11,12,13,14, or 15, I need those numbers to be replaced by A,B,C,D,E, and F, respectively. Here is an example:

Input: 3877

```
number = input("enter a number: ")
number = int(number)

remainders = list()

while number>0:
    remainders.append(str(number % 16))
    number//=16
print(*remainders[::-1], sep='')
```

current output (in hexadecimal): 1525
What I need output to be: F25

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map each decimal number from 0-16 to its corresponding hex single digit:

```
# number = input("enter a number: ")
# number = int(number)
number = 3877

remainders = []
lookup = {k:v for k, v in zip(range(16), '0123456789ABCDEF')}

if number == 0:
    remainders = ['0']

while number>0:
    remainders.append(lookup[number % 16])
    number//=16
print(*remainders[::-1], sep='')
```

#### output:

```
F25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
number = 3877

remainders = []
lookup = {k:v for k, v in enumerate('0123456789ABCDEF')}

while number>0:
    number, remainder = divmod(number, 16)
    remainders.append(lookup[remainder])
print(*remainders[::-1], sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with adding few more lines in your code:

first create two list one with character and one with integers which you want to map and then create dict from those :

```
list_1=["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
list_2=[10,11,12,13,14,15]

new_dict={i:j for i,j in zip(list_1,list_2)}
```

Now add these lines in last lines of code , for checking if input last digits are in dict , then get that value's key.

new=remainders[:]

```
for i in new:
    for j,k in new_dict.items():
        if k==i:
            print("{}{}".format(j,''.join(str(x) for x in remainders[::-1][1:])))
```

done.

full code:

```
list_1=["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
list_2=[10,11,12,13,14,15]

new_dict={i:j for i,j in zip(list_1,list_2)}



number = input("enter a number: ")
number = int(number)

remainders = list()

while number>0:
    remainders.append(int(number % 16))
    number//=16

new=remainders[:]

for i in new:
    for j,k in new_dict.items():
        if k==i:
            print("{}{}".format(j,''.join(str(x) for x in remainders[::-1][1:])))
```

running time:

```
enter a number: 3877

F25
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show an answer without a dict:

```
DHEX = '0123456789ABCDEF'
DHEX[12]    # 12 -> 'C'
```

The loop could then look like this - doing div(ision) and mod(ulo) in one step:

```
while number > 0:
    number, digit = divmod(number, 16) 
    remainders.append(DHEX[digit])
```